# Finding partial duplicate values and keeping a specific

Tags: java, list, duplicates, hashset

I have a list which contains a value and another list, in this case a trainNumber with corresponding list of Stations. However there are duplicate trainNumbers, which might have different stations. From this I am trying to create a new list keeping the trainNumbers which have the most stations.

For example if I have a list which contains:

```
String trainNumber = 1,  List trainNumber = [Station1, Station3]
String trainNumber = 2,  List trainNumber = [Station1, Station2, Station3]  
String trainNumber = 3,  List trainNumber = [Station1, Station3]  
String trainNumber = 3,  List trainNumber = [Station3]
```

I want the new list to contain:

```
String trainNumber = 1, List trainNumber = [Station1, Station3]  
String trainNumber = 2, List trainNumber = [Station1, Station2, Station3]  
String trainNumber = 3, List trainNumber = [Station1, Station3]
```

I have seen usage of Set to remove duplicate list items, however I need to specify which item I want to keep.

```
HashSet<Trains> newList = new HashSet<Trains>();
    for(Trains train: trainOverview){
        String trainNumber = train.getTrainNumber();
        int stationSize = train.getStations().size();
        int largest = 0;
        for(Trains trainCopy: trainOverview){
            if(trainNumber.equals(trainCopy.getTrainNumber())){
                int stationCopySize = trainCopy.getStations().size();
                if(stationCopySize > largest) largest = stationCopySize;
            }
        }
        if(togSize >= largest){
            newList.add(tog);
        }
    }

    trainOverview.clear();
    trainOverview.addAll(newList);
```

Now this kinda works, but I find it extremely messy. I am using HashSet to remove duplicates which have the same amount of stations (which also occurs). There surely must be a better way to go about this problem?

**EDIT**: Thanks for you answers, but i see that the put method replaces the value of the key. Im my case I would like to keep the values (stations) that were mapped the first time to the key(trainNumber) in addition to the new ones.

I've never worked with a Map before, but this is my approach (not sure if Im using it correct):

```
    Map<String, List<Station>> overview= new TreeMap<String, List<Station>>();
    for(Trains train: trainOverview){
        List<Stations> lista = overview.get(train.getTrainNumber());
        //Merge lists if the key already exists, and replace the old value with the merged list
        if(overview.containsKey(train.getTrainNumber())){
            Set setboth = new HashSet(lista);
            setboth.addAll(train.getStations());
            lista.clear();
            lista.addAll(setboth);
            overview.put(train.getTrainNumber(), lista);
        }
        //If no key exists, create a new entry
        else{
            overview.put(train.getTrainNumber(), train.getStations());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Create a mapping from trainNumbers to a set of stations and just fill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having two lists just use a `Map<String, List<Station>>`. The `trainNumber` would be the unique key and you could easily add or delete stations from the corresponding list in the map.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @ipavlic use `Map<String, Set<Station>>`, since a set allows no duplicate elements.

**UPDATE2**

Here a little example, with some comments. The example shows you just how to use a map combined with a set. You should **not** copy this into you code 1:1, since this is not a object-oriented approach. The map should be encapsulated in some object.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MapSetExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    System.out.println("ADDED = " + add(map, "Train1", "Station1"));
    System.out.println("ADDED = " + add(map, "Train1", "Station2"));
    System.out.println("ADDED = " + add(map, "Train1", "Station1"));

    System.out.println("Stations of Train1 = " + map.get("Train1"));

  }

  private static boolean add(Map<String, Set<String>> map, String key, String station) {
    Set<String> set = map.get(key);

    /* If map.get() returns null, that means there is no set
     * in the map associated with given key.
     * 
     * In that case we create a new set.
     * 
     * If there is already a set, we use that one.
     */
    if (set == null) {
      set = new TreeSet<String>();
      map.put(key, set);
    }
    /* False if station is already in set. At this point you could also delete sth. etc. */
    boolean success = set.add(station);
    return success;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ADDED = true
ADDED = true
ADDED = false
Stations of Train1 = [Station1, Station2]
```

Comment: Even better, make a list a set.

Comment: well considering train stations a `Set` might not be the best idea since it does not care for the order in which the train stops there

Comment: From the example OP posted, he sorted the stations by number, so he could use a `TreeSet`. But you are right, if the order of the elements has a semantic, then he should preferably use a list.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However im having problems with when combining the old Map value with the new one. Im trying to combine the list without duplicate values (as you can see in my EDIT). But I get duplicate stations.

Comment: I added some example code for you, that shows how to handle maps together with sets as values (you could also use this approach for list, other maps etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I think that better will be `Map<String, Set<Station>>`. `trainNumber` as unique key and `Set` for stations to avoid repetitions.